# Implementing a Modal Factory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'be been using modals as a means to communicate to users in my apps for some time now via several different front end frameworks. The logic is usually the same, defining the modal's html then rendering it via some click event.

As my applications grow, so do the number of modals I use for a user prompt or confirmation - these modals can have anything from text inputs to forms to dropdowns and so on.

My current method is to write out each separate modal in a single html file and simply call them by their IDs but I feel this is inefficient as there is plenty of duplicate boilerplate code, so I'm wondering the best way would be to create modals dynamically while keeping the code as light andclean as possible?

I've been thinking of something like a "modal factory" where you pass the content of the modal along with the height, width, styling, etc. would this be a good approach?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Though this would be an interesting subject to discus, discussion doesn't belong to SO. All the answers in Q&A mode will be opinion-based.

Comment: The content in the modal is it loaded via Ajax from the server?

Comment: Very well could be @DawoodAwan, I send data to & from the server via modal windows

Comment: @KuraiBankusu and what is the server side technology?

Comment: @DawoodAwan I code mostly in Java, branching out to Python

Answer (score 1):

Well what I do for `Forms/HTML Content` loaded from the server - is create a div with an ID - `PartialViewDialog` at the end of my page -(I load Partial Views inside a Dialog)

This one is Bootstrap 3.* based - (HTML structure based on Frontend framework

So the HTML is like this:

```
<body>

<!-- Other page content -->


<div class="modal fade" id="PartialViewDialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" data-modal="title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-modal="content">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" data-modal="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Then in JS, I create a dialog Manager:

```
   var MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.UIHelper = MyApp.UIHelper || {};

MyApp.UIHelper.DialogManager = (function () {

    "use strict";


    var self = {};
    self.divId = null;
    self.dialog = null;
    self.dialogBody = null;
    self.dialogTitle = null;
    self.dialogFooter = null;
    self.actionUrl = "";
    self.modalObject = null;
    self.options = {};

    function Initilize(divId, options) {

        self.options = $.extend({ buttons: [] }, options);
        self.divId = divId;
        self.dialog = $(self.divId);
        self.dialogBody = self.dialog.find('*[data-modal="content"]');
        self.dialogTitle = self.dialog.find('*[data-modal="title"]');
        self.dialogFooter = self.dialog.find('*[data-modal="footer"]');
        self.BootgridObject = null;
    };

    function OpenPartialViewDialog(url, title, preprocessingFunction, postProcessingFunction) {

        // Create the buttons
        var options = self.GetPartialViewButtons(url, preprocessingFunction, postProcessingFunction);

        // Initialise the PartialViewDialog with Buttons
        Initilize('#PartialViewDialog', options);

        // Set the URL for Ajax content load and Form Post
        self.actionUrl = url;

        // Set Dialog Title
        self.dialogTitle.html(title);

        // Open the PartialViewDialog
        self.OpenModel();
    };


    // This Method creates the buttons for the Form dialog
    // e.g Save, Cancel, Ok buttons
    self.GetPartialViewButtons = function (url, preprocessingFunction, postProcessingFunction) {

        // I only need Save and Cancel buttons always so I create them here
        var buttons = {
            buttons: {
        // I create a save button which Posts back the Form in the Dialog
                Save: {
                    Text: "Save",
                    css: "btn btn-success",
                    click: function () {

                        // Call a function before sending the Ajax request to submit form
                        if (preprocessingFunction) { preprocessingFunction(); }

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            // This Dialog has a Form - which is Post back to server
                            data: self.dialogBody.find("form").serialize(),
                            success: function (response) {
                                // TODO: Check if response is success - 
                                // Apply your own logic here
                                if (response.hasOwnProperty("IsSuccess")) {

                                    if (response.IsSuccess) {
                                        self.dialogBody.html("");
                                        self.dialog.modal("hide");
                                        // TODO: Show Success Message
                                        // You can call another function if you want
                                        if (postProcessingFunction) {
                                            postProcessingFunction();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        // If failure show Error Message    
                                    }
                                } 
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                               // If failure show Error Message 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                Cancel: {
                    Text: "Cancel",
                    css: "btn btn-danger",
                    click: function () {
                        self.dialogBody.html("");
                        self.dialogFooter.html("");
                        self.dialogTitle.html("");
                        self.dialog.modal("hide");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return buttons;
    };


    // dynamic creating the button objects
    self.CreateButtonsHtml = function () {
        var htmlButtons = [];
        $.each(self.options.buttons, function (name, props) {
            var tempBtn = $("<button/>", {
                text: props.Text,
                id: "btn_" + props.Text,
                "class": props.css + "",
                click: props.click
            }).attr({ "style": "margin-right: 5px;" });

            htmlButtons.push(tempBtn);

        });
        return htmlButtons;
    };


    // This method will load the content/form from server and assign the modal body - it will assign the buttons to the Modal Footer and Open the Dialog for user
    self.OpenModel = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: self.actionUrl,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (response) {          
                // Handle response from server - 
                // I send JSON object if there is Error in loading the content - otherwise the result is HTML           
                if (response.hasOwnProperty("HasErrors")) { 
                    // Means some error has occured loading the content - you will have to apply your own logic
                } else {

                    //Server return HTML - assign to the modal body HTML        
                    self.dialogBody.html(response);
                    self.modalObject = self.dialog.modal();
                    // show modal
                    self.modalObject.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Create the buttons in the Dialog footer
        var buttons = self.CreateButtonsHtml();
        self.dialogFooter.html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            self.dialogFooter.append(buttons[i]);
        }
    };
    return {
        OpenPartialViewDialog: OpenPartialViewDialog,
    };

})();
```

Then whenever I need to open a dialog from the server I can call it like this:

```
MyApp.UIHelper.DialogManager
          .OpenPartialViewDialog('/Content/Load', "My Title", 
                          function(){alert('pre-process')}, 
                          function(){alert('post-process')}
                  );
```

**Note: The PreProcess + PostProcess are called when the Save button is clicked**

Here is a working/demo example which shows what the above JS does - Hope it helps
In the demo I load Dummy HTML from a div `id="dummycontent"`

#### Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1L0eLazf/

#### Button Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1L0eLazf/1/